# Rails calculate in where

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, where-clause

my app has items table with columns price and count.
I need display a list of items for which price multiplied with count > than some number.
Now my code looks like this

```
items.where("count * price >= 100")
```

Can I change it as anything? Interested in any variants.
Thank you

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but i need list of items, where  count * price >= 100 =) not a count

Comment: Have you tried the first query of my post?

Comment: SQLite3::SQLException: near "*": syntax error:

Comment: You have to be more precise about this error, can you post the full error message please?

Comment: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in ItemsController#show SQLite3::SQLException: near "*": syntax error: SELECT items.*, COUNT(items.*) AS count, (count * items.price) AS total FROM "items" WHERE (total >= 100) ORDER BY "items"."id" ASC LIMIT 1

Comment: from which "star" (*) does the error comes from? The one at `items.*` or in the `COUNT(items.*)` or in the `count* items.price` part?

Comment: Try with `COUNT(*) AS count` instead (without the `items.`)

Comment: This worked, but return only last result

Comment: Is it because there is only one record with `count*price >= 100`?

Comment: Did my answer help finally?

Answer (score 2):

If you need to re-use this calculation, you can select it and give it an alias for SQL:

```
items = items.select('items.*, COUNT(items.*) AS count, (count * items.price) AS total').where('total >= 100')
```

And then use directly the total variable:

```
items.first.total # => Should return the count*price
items.first.count # => Should return the count
items.first.id # => You can call all the other attributes of an Item
```

---

You can also make a scope of it:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base

   scope :total_more_than, lambda do |total|
     self.select('items.*, COUNT(items.*) AS count, (count * items.price) AS total').where('total >= ?', total || 100) # if not total given, will use 100
   end
```

And use it like this:

```
items.total_more_than(100)
```